# What is the exact meaning of "patch level"?

Tags: versioning

While in general terms I realize this is a sub-version number that's bumped based on patches that don't bump the major version, is there a more exact definition for this?

Must the number match the number of patches applied for example?

Or is this a general term that each project uses slightly differently?

Comment: Replying to the flag that this question is "Opinion Based" - there are quire a few questions about meanings of terminology on this site, e.g: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118158 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163090

Comment: Both of those questions are from before the site changed its scope. Also, the fact that a question exists on the site is not proof that it is on-topic, it is only proof that it has not been removed yet. Moderation is done by volunteers in their spare time, so it *might* be on-topic, or it might be that nobody deemed if worth the effort to close it. And lastly, neither of those questions really ask for the definition of a term. One asks a focused question about the different usage of the term in two concrete examples, the other asks about a concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest we have to an accepted definition of "patch level" comes from [semantic versioning (semver)](https://semver.org/), where a patch level is the third component of a version number, which gets increased if a release only contains backward compatible bug fixes.

However, semver is not universally used and others may use the term "patch level" in other ways.